# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}=e\ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to prove $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}=e\ $?

I thought about it but I could not find a proof. Please give me some hints?

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: $e=2.71828182835...$

Comment: You need to have a more "formal" definition of $e$ for a start.

Comment: That's not a definition of $e$. That's just the first digits of $e$. @athos

Comment: Never mind. Wiki told me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Complex_numbers

Comment: Adding to Thomas's comment: you're still short a lot of digits to get $\;e\;$ ...

Comment: @MikeMiller: Isn't that obvious that it is an Euler Constant?

Comment: @jojek But you can define Euler's constant in a lot of different ways, and *that affects the proof.* If you ask someone to prove that $a=b$ you need to know how $a$ and $b$ are defined to know what you need to prove it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I believe that corresponding equation allows you to prove that in only one way, i.e. no point in using definition: $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{t}dt=1$, therefore no point in asking about definition. It's rather obvious to me which approach to use. But I see, it is only the way mathematicians think... "How much is 2+2"? "Define +"

Comment: @jojek, asking for a proof is like asking for directions (to a building in a city).  Some buildings are at the end of a long single road and there is more or less only one way to get there (although there may be a shortcut through the woods).  Other buildings are in the middle of a complicated tangle of one-way highways, and it matters very much whether you're starting on the east side of town or on the south side of town.  Questions like this about $e$ are of this type.

Comment: @jojek There are least 4 natural definitions of the exponential function, and hence of $e=exp(1)$: as the reciprocal of the logarithm, as the sum of the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$, via the differential equation $y'=y$, or by the formula $exp(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{x}n\right)^n$. It takes some time to show that these definitions do define the same function, and hence that, for example, $\sum_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ is indeed the same number as the one implicitely defined by the equation $\int_1^e\frac{dt}t=1$. These questions are quite deep (though still "elementary").

Comment: @athos: I think that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) article is exactly what you need, since it proves the equivalence of the various different expressions for the exponential function.

Comment: @jojek: if there is an obvious approach to prove the identity, could you provide it as an answer? "It is obvious" is a little bit short.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many ways to define $e,$ but somewhere along the line you have to define it before you can hope to prove it equal to some other quantity. If you define the function $e^{x}$ by the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!},$ which converges for all real $x,$ then you just need to substitute $x =1$ to obtain what you want. I don't imagine this was the intention when the question was set.

There are two other fairly common rigorous ways to define $e,$ but one is really covered by what is said already- that is, if we define the $\log$ function by $\log(x) = \int^{x}_{1} \frac{1}{t}dt$ for $x >0,$ then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\log$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty),$ and $\log^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for all positive $x.$ Hence $\log$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty),$ and, in particular, is one-to-one. We define $\exp$ to be the inverse function of $\log,$ and we find easily that 
$\exp^{\prime} = \exp,$ from which it easily follows that the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!},$ which we have dealt with.

The method defining $e$ which makes this problem most challenging is as $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}.$ However, note that for every $n >0,$ we have 
$$(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{n^{k}k!(n-k)!} $$ 
which may be rewritten as 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}  \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} ( 1 - \frac{j}{n}).$$

This is always less than 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$$
and greater than 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}  ( 1 - \frac{k}{n})^{k-1}.$$
Now fix a large integer $M.$ Then when $n >M,$ the last sum is greater than $$\sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}  ( 1 - \frac{M}{n})^{M-1}.$$

As $n \to \infty,$ the last expression tends to $\sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}.$

We have proved that 
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$
for all $n,$ and that for any fixed integer $M,$ we have 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+ \frac{1}{n})^{n} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}.$$
Hence 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}.$$

Comment: "we find easily that exp′=exp". Can you please elaborate? :)

Comment: Set $g(x) = \log(x)$ and $f(x)$ to be the inverse function, so that $f(g(x))=  g(f(x)) = x.$ Then $f^{\prime}(x)g^{\prime}(f(x)) = x^{\prime} = 1,$ while $g^{\prime}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f(x)}.$ Hence $f^{\prime}(x) = f(x).$ Strictly, this does not prove that $\exp$ is differentiable as it stands, but that can be done with more care.

Comment: A missing $f'(x)$ on the numerator?

Comment: @enzotib: No, I don't think so: The second sentence is really saying that $\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)} = 1,$ but I am using the chain rule applied to $g$ composed with $f,$ and getting $\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)} =1,$ which is correct.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

First look at the derivative of $2^x$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} 2^x & = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{2^{x+\delta} - 2^x}{\delta}
\\ & = 2^x \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac {2^\delta - 1}{\delta}
\end{align}
$$

Let $f(x) = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^\delta - 1}{\delta}$, which can be evaluated numerically.  $\frac{d}{dx} 2^x = 2^x f(2)$ and $f(2) \approx 0.693$.  Likewise $\frac{d}{dx} 3^x = 3^x f(3)$ and $f(3) \approx 1.08$.  What's the derivative of $f$?

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f(x) & = \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\gamma) - f(x)}{\gamma}
\\ &= \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{(x + \gamma)^\delta - 1}{\delta} - \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{x^\delta -1}{\delta}}
{\gamma}
\\ &= \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{(x + \gamma)^\delta - x^\delta}{\delta}}{\gamma}
\\ &= \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{(x + \gamma)^\delta - x^\delta}{\gamma}}{\delta}
\\ &= \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ \frac{d}{dx} x^\delta}{\delta} = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ \delta x^{\delta - 1}}{\delta} = \dfrac{1}{x}
\end{align}$$

This tells us that $f$ is mononically increasing between 2 and 3, so there must be a unique value of $x$ for which $f(x) = 1$.

$e$ is defined as the number for which $f(e) = 1$ and $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$.  Think about the Taylor series for $e^x = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 ... = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i$.

It has a value of 1 at $x = 0$, so $a_0 = 1$.  Since it is equal to its derivative, the derivatives of all the individual terms must be equal, i.e. $\forall i \ge 0: a_i x^i = (i+1) a_{i+1} x^i$.  $a_0 = 1$ and $a_i = (i+1)a_{i+1}$ and $\frac{a_i}{i+1} = a_{i+1}$.  This means $a_i = \frac1{i!}$ and $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}$.

Evaluate the polynomial at x=1 and you get your expression for $e$.

Comment: Shouldn't $a_0 = 1$?

Comment: How does one know there is a number $a$ such that $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x$?

Comment: @AhmedAli fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Improve $\frac{d}{dx} 2^x \approx 0.69 \cdot 2^x$, and $\frac{d}{dx} 3^x \approx 1.08 \cdot 3^x$, and the limit from which this constant is derived is nice and smooth around $2$ and $3$, so there must be a "goldilocks" number $2 < a < 3$ such that  $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the taylor formula, assuming that for you $e = \exp(1)$ and $\exp' = \exp$.

$$
e - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!} =  \int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^n}{n!} \exp(t) dt
$$

Now use $0\le \exp(t) \le \exp(1) =C $ on $(0,1)$ to get
$$
0\le e - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!} \le C\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^n}{n!}  dt
= \frac C{n+1}\to 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove it is using differential equations. It's fairly straightforward to show that there exists a unique function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$, which can be proven by noting that $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x) = \frac1x$ and $f^{-1}(1) = 0$, which implies $f^{-1}(x) = \int_1^x\frac1t dt$.

The next step is to show that there exists a constant $e$ such that $f(x) = e^x$. Let $e = f(1)$. Notice that $\frac{f(x + y)}{f(y)}$, seen as a function of $x$, solves the same initial value problem $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$. Uniqueness therefore implies $$
\frac{f(x+y)}{f(y)} = f(x)
$$ 
and hence $f(x+1) = f(1) f(x)$, and therefore $f(x) = f(1)^x = e^x$. Next, observe that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges absolutely for all $x$ which can be seen by the root test. Differentiating term by term we can see that this sum is its own derivative, and of course at $x= 0 $ it converges to $1$. Hence $e^x = f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. The conclusion is $$
e = f(1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}
$$