# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k}=1$ imply $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n,k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

From the reasoning in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154377/why-the-two-expressions-for-number-e-converge-to-the-same-number), I think that if a series $\sum a_n$ of positive terms converges and for each $1\le k\le n$, we have a number $0<b_{n,k}\le1$, and for each $k$ it is $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k}=1$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n,k}$$
Is that correct? If it is, can be the conditions about $b_{n,k}$ be relaxed in any way?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. My apologies for the wrong answer.

Comment: No problem. I took a pretty while writing the question... It is complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices that $(a_n)$ is absolutely convergent, $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k}=1$ for all $k$, and that $(b_{n,k})$ is  bounded.

Then $|a_n| \le K$, $|b_{n,k}| \le M$, and for $1 < N < n$ is
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n,k} \right|
\le \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k| |1-b_{n,k}|
\le K \sum_{k=1}^N |1-b_{n,k}| + (1+M) \sum_{k=N+1}^n |a_k| \, .
$$
Now, given $\epsilon > 0$, one can first choose $N > 0$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^n |a_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(1+M)}$, and then choose $n_0 > N$ such that $|1-b_{n,k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2KN}$ for $1 \le k \le N$ and $n \ge n_0$. It follows that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n,k} \right| < \epsilon
$$
for  $n\ge n_0$, so that the limits are equal.

This can also be shown with the help of the dominated convergence theorem for integrals with respect to the counting measure on the positive integers: Let $f, f_n: \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ be the functions defined by
$$
\begin{align}
 f(k) &= a_k \, ,\\
 f_n(k) &= \begin{cases}
a_k b_{n,k} &\quad \text{ if } k \le n \, ,\\
 0 &\quad\text{ if } k > n \, ,
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
and $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\Bbb N$. Then $|f_n(k)| \le M |f(k)|$ and $f$ is integrable, so that the DCT can be applied:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n,k} = \int_{\Bbb N} f_n(k) d\mu \to \int_{\Bbb N} f(k) d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k
$$
for $n \to \infty$.

If all $a_n$ and $b_{n,k}$ are non-negative and $b_{n,k}$ *increases* to $1$ for each fixed $k$, then monotone convergence theorem (Beppo Levi's lemma) can be applied. It follows that under these conditions, the identity holds even if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$.